# How to populate a cuboid based on compositions in java mc bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, composition

So i'm currently having an issue whereby i need to populate a cuboid with certain blocks , now basically its a mine containing different ores in minecraft , but it needs to be randomly based off of some compositions for example  :

```
public class Composition {

    private ItemStack stack;
    private float percentage;

    public Composition(ItemStack stack, float percentage) {
        this.stack = stack;
        this.percentage = percentage;

    }
    public ItemStack getStack() {
        return stack;
    }

    public float getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setStack(ItemStack stack) {
        this.stack = stack;
    }

    public void setPercentage(float percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

then the code that resets this mine is as follows  :

```
   for ( Block b : region ) {
        float chance = r.nextFloat();

        int select = random.nextInt(compositions.size());

        Composition comp = compositions.get(select);

        if (chance <= comp.getPercentage()) {
            b.setType(comp.getStack().getType());
            b.setData((byte) comp.getStack().getDurability());
        } else {
            b.setType(defaultType.getType());
            b.setData((byte) defaultType.getDurability());
        }
```

Basically the region is a List of blocks , each block has a type.

as u can see what i tried to do was to generate a random chance float /percentage that the single block , can/should be changed

then i randomly pull an element out of this list of Compositions
based on the percentage of the random chance and the composition percentage i myt set the block to the type of the composition , however i feel like this is not accurate at all.

if someone could come up with a better way or idea to do this that would me a lot thanks.

[image: Screenshot of the Mine Compositions]

[image: An image just to imagine how the mine looks virtually]

I'm not sure if my explanation makes sense so bottom line is i'm trying to form a mine/cuboid of random blocks of different types based on compositions.

**EG :**
Mine has 100 x blocks
            **Compositions :**
               IRON_ORE 20 % (0.2F) = 20x Blocks should be IRON
               STONE 80 % (0.8F) = 80x Blocks should be STONE

so the whole mine should contain 20% IRON_ORE randomly though not like placed 1 after the other.
STONE will basically take up the whole percentage of the mine but there should be bits of iron randomly seen.

**Edited.**

I think i managed to find a sort of solution , but if anyone has other opinions or ideas please let me know.

```
  Random r = new Random();

    float ratio = region.getBlocks().size() / 100;
    List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>(region.getBlocks());

    for (Composition c : compositions) {

        double blocksToChange = Math.floor((float)(ratio * c.getPercentage()));

        for(int i = 0; i <= blocksToChange ; i++){
            if( blocks.size() <= 0 ) break;

            Block b = blocks.get(r.nextInt(blocks.size()));
            //Change block
            b.setType(c.getStack().getType());
            b.setData((byte) c.getStack().getDurability());
            //Remove it
            blocks.remove(b);
        }
    }
```

/// This is for the remaining blocks that cant be calculated with the Math.floor.

```
    for(Block b : blocks){

        Composition c = compositions.get(r.nextInt(compositions.size()));

        b.setType(c.getStack().getType());
        b.setData((byte) c.getStack().getDurability());
    }
```